# Add namespace prefix Axis2

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-axis

This is envelope which i wanna to send to service:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <sear:searchUrls>
            <sear:in0>Safeway, 200 S. 3rd St, Renton, WA</sear:in0>
        </sear:searchUrls>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And this is code to construct it:

```
SOAPFactory fac = OMAbstractFactory.getSOAP12Factory();
SOAPEnvelope envelope = fac.getDefaultEnvelope();

OMNamespace omNs = fac.createOMNamespace("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", "soapenv");
OMNamespace ns1 = fac.createOMNamespace("http://search", "sear");

envelope.setNamespace(omNs);

OMNamespace ns = fac.createOMNamespace("", "")
OMElement method = fac.createOMElement("sear:searchUrls", ns);
OMElement value = fac.createOMElement("sear:in0", ns);
value.setText("Safeway, 200 S. 3rd St, Renton, WA");
method.addChild(value);
envelope.getBody().addChild(method);
```

But my namespace prefix "sear" is not defined. 
How can I set it in code to get

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sear="http://search">
```

in XML?

Comment: You need to review the XML snippet that is supposed to show what you want to send to the service. It mixes SOAP 1.1 and SOAP 1.2, and there is no namespace declaration for the `sear` prefix. It is therefore invalid. I suspect that the snippet shows the actual output of the code and not the message that you want to generate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("sear", "http://search");
```

Comment: The method `addNamespaceDeclaration()`doesn't exist. use `envelope.declareNamespace("URI","Prefix")` instead

Answer (score 1):

```
    OMNamespace xsi = soapFactory.createOMNamespace(
            Constants.URI_DEFAULT_SCHEMA_XSI,
            Constants.NS_PREFIX_SCHEMA_XSI);

    envelope.declareNamespace(xsi);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the WSDL and know the end point url ?
You can generate the client side code using the wsdl2java convertor.

More information at http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide-creatingclients.html#choosingclient